# why do javascript libraries using json choose a [ { } , { } ] structure

Tags: php, json, javascript

I've been using a few javascript libraries, and I noticed that most of them take input in this form: `[{"foo": "bar", "12": "true"}]`

According to [json.org:](http://json.org)

[image]

So we  are sending an object in an array.

So I have a two part question:

**Part 1:**
Why not just send an object or an array, which would seem simpler?

**Part2:**
What is the best way to create such a Json with Php?

Here is a working method, but I found it a bit ugly as it does not work out of the box with multi-dimensional arrays:

```
    <?php 
$object[0] = array("foo" => "bar", 12 => true); 

$encoded_object = json_encode($object); 
?>
```

output:

`{"1": {"foo": "bar", "12": "true"}}`

```
<?php $encoded = json_encode(array_values($object)); ?>
```

output:

`[{"foo": "bar", "12": "true"}]`

Comment: You send an array of objects, if there is only one object need to send, then you could just send an object.

Comment: `array(array("foo" => "bar", 12 => true))`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Because that's the logical way how to pass *multiple objects*. It's probably made to facilitate this:

   ```
   [{"foo" : "bar", "12" : "true"}, {"foo" : "baz", "12" : "false"}]
   ```
2. Use the same logical structure in PHP:

   ```
   echo json_encode(array(array("foo" => "bar", "12" => "true")));
   ```

Comment: As an addendum, the added benefit, when dealing with JSON delivered in this format would be to run through a `for` loop, like `for(....){ tweet = tweets[i]; tweet_card = build_tweet(tweet);  frag.appendChild(tweet_card); }`, and all of a sudden, your view logic is pretty compact, and it all makes complete sense, as you're dealing with individual units passed in a collection.  If it were done with explicitly-named object keys (ie: `tweet1, tweet2` or timestamps or anything else, it would be much more difficult to isolate individual units).  It's all about the end-game.

Answer (score 0):

An array is used as a convenient way to support multiple parameters. The first parameter, in this case, is an object.

Comment: Doesn't answer the full question.

Comment: There are two unrelated questions.

Answer (score 0):

Question one:

JSON is just a way of representing an object and/or and array as a string. If you have your array or object as a string, it is much easier to send it around to different places, like to the client's browser. Different languages handle arrays and objects in different ways. So if you had an array in php, for example, you can't send it to the client directly because it is in a format that only php understands. This is why JSON is useful. It is a method of converting an array or object to a string that lots of different languages understand.

Question two:

To output an array of objects like the above, you could do this:

```
<?php
    //create a test array of objects
    $testarray = array();
    $testarray[] = json_decode('{"type":"apple", "number":4, "price":5}');
    $testarray[] = json_decode('{"type":"orange", "number":3, "price":8}');
    $testarray[] = json_decode('{"type":"banana", "number":8, "price":3}');
    $testarray[] = json_decode('{"type":"coconut", "number":2, "price":9}');

    $arraycount = count($testarray);


    echo("[");

    $i = 1;
    foreach($testarray as $object)
    {
        echo(json_encode($object));
        if($i !== $arraycount)
        {
            echo(",");
        }

        $i += 1;
    }

    echo("]");
?>
```

This will take an array of objects and loop over them. Before we loop over them, we output the opening square bracket.

Then, for each object in the array, we output it encoded to JSON plus a comma after each one. We count the number of iterations so that we don't output a comma at the end.

Comment: json_encode does work on multi-dimensional arrays,but I didn't know how to produce a [{ }] structure with it.